# Java 8 convert Map<Department, List<Person>> to Map<Department, List<String>>

Tags: dictionary, collections, java-8, java-stream

Using `Collectors.groupingBy()` I can easily obtain a `Map<Department, List<Person>>` - this gives me all the `Person` objects that are part of a `Department`:

```
allPersons.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getDepartment));
```

Now I would like to convert the resulting 'multimap' so that it contains all Persons' names and not the `Person` objects.

One way to achieve this is:

```
final Map<Department, List<String>> newMap = new HashMap<>();
personsByDepartmentMap.stream
    .forEach((d, lp) -> newMap.put(
         d, lp.stream().map(Person::getName).collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Is there a way to achieve this without using the `newMap` object?
Something like

```
final Map<Department, List<String>> newMap = 
                personsByDepartmentMap.stream().someBigMagic();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the map using

```
Map<Department, List<String>> result =
    personsByDepartmentMap.entrySet().stream()
      .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(
        e.getKey(),
        e.getValue().stream().map(Person::getName).collect(Collectors.toList())))
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

This code obviously suffers from the fact that there is no standard `Pair` type but you can improve it by using `static import`s.

(Update:) As [Brian Goetz has shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28072111/2711488) you can work-around it in this specific case by combining the mapping and collection into one step, e.g.

```
Map<Department, List<String>> result =personsByDepartmentMap.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        e->e.getValue().stream().map(Person::getName).collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

---

However, I still think it’s easier to retrieve the map from your original `List` in one operation:

```
Map<Department, List<String>> collect = allPersons.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Person::getDepartment,
        Collectors.mapping(Person::getName, Collectors.toList())
    ));
```

This too would benefit from `static import`s:

```
Map<Department, List<String>> collect = allPersons.stream().collect(
    groupingBy(Person::getDepartment, mapping(Person::getName, toList())));
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Map<Dept, List<String>> namesInDept
    = peopleInDept.entrySet().stream()
                  .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                                 e -> e.getValue().stream()
                                                  .map(Person::getName)
                                                  .collect(toList()));
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you didn't need the intermediary `Map<Person, List<Department>>` type. If that's the case, you can do it all in one step:

```
Map<Department, List<String>> result = allPersons.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getDepartment,
        Collectors.mapping(Person::getName, Collectors.toList())
    )
);
```